# Bootstrap - vertical align form group label on top, input at bottom

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a form that uses Bootstrap 4.4. The form groups contain a label and an input and sometimes also a select and when the select is present it breaks the alignment of the labels and inputs on the same row.

How to keep the labels always on top and the input at the bottom? I want to do this without custom Css and additional html elements if possible.

```html
<div class="row col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-group">
        <label for="value">Value:</label>
        <select>
            <option>something</option>
        </select>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-group">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: And it looks like this]

Using justify on one of the containers I got all the inputs to allign at the bottom but I want to keep the labels at the top.

*Edit*: I need to keep the layout like this, with the two (or more) form groups on one row:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you add label -> class="w-100" it will take width:100% so it won't take any element to the same row with itself. To keep inputs always at the end of the form group you can add something on top of them. Also if you give the same design for selects and other form elements it will look better.

```
<div class="row col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-group">
        <label class="w-100" for="value">Value:</label>
        <select>
            <option>something</option>
        </select>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 form-group">
        <label class="w-100" for="name">Name:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see what you mean but I want to keep the layout as it is now, with two form groups on the same row. Just that I want the labels to be all vertically aligned and the inputs too

Comment: can you visualize what you say? I understand like vertically order -> label - input -label - select - input. Is it like this??

Comment: I added a pic, hope it helps @ates_irem